# Is it possible to use mylatex or mylatexformat for documents with preambles almost the same?

Tags: packages, geometry, lengths, format-files

I have documents of this form:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\variableLength}
\setlength{\variableLength}{xxxx cm}

\usepackage{package1}
\usepackage{package2}
\usepackage{package3}

\makeatletter
% some macros
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\input{...}
\end{document}
```

where `xxxx` can take multiple values.

Is it still possible to make benefit (I have to make the compilations multiple times) of `mylatex` or `mylatexformat`?

### Remark

The value is used as follows

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm, 
            paperheight=\variableLength,
            left=5mm,
            right=5mm,
            top=5mm,
            bottom=5mm]{geometry}
```

and that's all.

Comment: What are "mylatex" and "mylatexformat"? Please advise.

Comment: See https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mylatex and https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mylatexformat

Comment: If `\setlength{\variableLength}{xxxx cm}` is the only preamble instruction that can vary, have you considered moving it out of the preamble, i.e., placing it *after* `\begin{document}`?

Comment: I think using `mylatexformat` instead of `mylatex` will do the trick.

Comment: @Mico that's impossible because I use  `\variableLength` in a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command in `mylatexformat` for this purpose. In your preamble, use the command `\endofdump` to delimit the end of the common part of your preambles.